# Applying percentile values stored in dataframe to an array

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a percentile dataframe `df` as follows:

```
            col1   col2     
GDStart                                                                   
2019-09-02  100    11  
2019-09-03   60    16  
2019-09-04   60    67
```

I have another array `data`:

```
array([1.65 , 1.68 , 1.755, 1.76 , 1.63 ])
```

I need to perform the following using information in `df` to get percentile dataframe `dt`:

```
import numpy as np

            col1                       col2     
GDStart                                                                   
2019-09-02  np.percentile(data, 100)   np.percentile(data, 11)
2019-09-03  np.percentile(data, 60)    np.percentile(data, 16)  
2019-09-04  np.percentile(data, 60)    np.percentile(data, 67)
```

I am not sure how to map the `dataframe` with `np.percentile`.

Comment: do you want to use all 5 array data to calculate percentile for each columns ?

Comment: Yes, basically use the data in `df` to calculate the percentile for `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do using `apply`

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.percentile(data, x))

output:

            col1    col2
GDStart     
2019-09-02  1.76    1.6388
2019-09-03  1.71    1.6428
2019-09-04  1.71    1.7310
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use `['col1','col2']`

Comment: you cant apply percentile on datetime column.

Comment: `datetime` column is the index however

Comment: oh, you are right, dont need to select the columns, i'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use listcomp and `np.transpose`

```
df[:] = np.transpose([np.percentile(data, df[col]) for col in df])

Out[546]:
            col1    col2
GDStart
2019-09-02  1.76  1.6388
2019-09-03  1.71  1.6428
2019-09-04  1.71  1.7310
```